# Preventing a tkinter Entry from gaining focus when its associated StringVar changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter Entry with a validate command, to be executed when the entry gets focus ("focusin"). This Entry is associated with a `StringVar`. It seems that whenever the StringVar changes value, the Entry gets focus, triggering the validation command. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
def validate(*args):
    print("Validation took place")
    return True
entry = tk.Entry(validate="focusin", validatecommand=validate)
print("Entry created. Associating textvariable")
entry.config(textvariable=var)
print("textvariable associated. Changing value")
var.set("Text")
print("Value changed")
entry.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

This code generates the following output:

```
Entry created. Associating textvariable
textvariable associated. Changing value
Validation took place
Value changed
```

Note that the validation command was executed, caused by a call to `var.set`.
Is there a way for me to change the value of the StringVar without causing its associated Entry to gain focus? I can't temporarily disassociate the StringVar from the Entry, because when re-associating them, the Entry also gains focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is to disable the validation event before setting the stringvar, and re-enable it afterwards.

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
def validate(*args):
    print("Validation took place")
    return True
entry = tk.Entry(validate="focusin", validatecommand=validate)
print("Entry created. Associating textvariable")
entry.config(textvariable=var)
print("textvariable associated. Changing value")
entry.config(validate="none")
var.set("Text")
entry.config(validate="focusin")
print("Value changed")
entry.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

If you expect to do this a lot, you could even write a context manager so you don't accidentally forget to re-enable validation after you're finished altering the text.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def temp_change(widget, **kargs):
    old_values = {key:widget.cget(key) for key in kargs}
    widget.config(**kargs)
    try:
        yield #wait for `with` block to finish executing...
    finally:
        widget.config(**old_values)


window = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
def validate(*args):
    print("Validation took place")
    return True
entry = tk.Entry(validate="focusin", validatecommand=validate)
print("Entry created. Associating textvariable")
entry.config(textvariable=var)
print("textvariable associated. Changing value")

with temp_change(entry, validate="none"):
    var.set("Text")

print("Value changed")
entry.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but it feels terribly hackish. The issue is exacerbated by the fact that I'm actually subclassing the Entry class, where the subclass takes care of binding the validationcommand, but the `var.set(...)` happens outside of the class. I find it ugly that the "user" has to know not to just plainly change the variable without side-effects happening.  If nothing else pops up soon, though, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you that it's not a beautiful solution. If it were me I'd probably stick the Entry and StringVar and validationcommand all in a single class and only expose them through a sensible interface of my own design. (I haven't done that in my answer because the specific design depends on the specific needs the extended Entry would be fulfilling)

Answer (score 2):

I think your observation is incorrect: the focus does not change when you set the value of the `StringVar`. This is likely just an edge case that only happens when your application first starts up. The widget probably gets focus when it is initially created. Once the GUI is up and running, setting the variable won't change the focus.

The [official tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7) discourages the use of both validation and the use of a variable. From the documentation:

> In general, the textVariable and validateCommand can be dangerous to mix. Any problems have been overcome so that using the validateCommand will not interfere with the traditional behavior of the entry widget.

There's no reason to use a `StringVar` in this case. My recommendation is to remove it. The use of a `StringVar` is generally only useful if you use the same variable for more than one widget, or you're putting a trace on the variable. You are doing neither so just stop using the `StringVar`. It adds an extra object to manage without providing much extra benefit.

Comment: What I posted is just a small example that displays the behaviour. My actual use case does also find this behaviour after the GUI is up and running, unfortunately. I wasn't aware that combining variables and validation were discouraged - I'll see if I can change my code not to need it.

Comment: Well, it's possible you'll see the same behavior, but it's not because the focus actually changes. You can easily see this by adding a second entry widget, and a button that sets the value. Set focus to the other entry, click the button, and see that focus does not change. The problem is _not_ that the focus is changing, but rather, the validation is happening _regardless of the focus_.